# Double-formatting in com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper

Tags: java, jackson, formatting, double, objectmapper

I have an application, which loads a data row from a SQL Server database and should transmit that content JSON-encoded to a webservice. I used ObjectMapper to do the JSON conversion. There is some infrastructure behind this project, namely I get the data from the db as a `Hashmap<string,object>` where the keys are the column-names from the db-table.

Is there a way to tell com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper how to format double-values upon serialization, when you can not use annotations?

I did a simple

```
ObjectMapper o = new ObjectMapper(); 
String jsonStr = o.writeValueAsString(m); // m is my hashmap-instance
```

While in theory this works quite nicely, I have a problem with the serialization of doubles. In the db there is a column of type `float`  (which corresponds to double in Java, java-float would be `real` in SQL Server) with the value `402.4818`. If I let ObjectMapper serialize this, I get `402.48179999999996` in JSON.

How can I customize the double-formatting / precision in ObjectMapper? I have already used `setDateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"))` to get my dates right, is there any way to do something similar for double?
Most examples in the net serialize POJOs where you can use annotations to specify how specific properties should be serialized, but I have a HashMap here.

Please don't tell me that I have to go through the hassle of creating a POJO, fill it with the DB-Data and serialize it for every row I want to send via this API. (This is a db-row which has > 30 columns and the project is nearly done, besides this little double-formatting-problem.)

So what do I need to do to tell ObjectMapper to round to the 4. decimal point before serializing or give some custom `DecimalFormat`? Documentation on this is quite sparse.

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example for this? If I do `m.put("a", 402.4818d);` and run your code, I get `{"a":402.4818}`

Comment: Are you sure that upon read from db your double value is 402.4818 and not 402.48179999999996 already? Maybe the problem is not in jackson but in the mapping of db data to java?

Comment: Maybe this will help: [jackson - json encoding of doubles with controlled precision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7299576/jackson-json-encoding-of-doubles-with-controlled-precision)